# difference between object parameter and generic parameter(type parameter)

Tags: c#, generics

I was thinking about the difference between object parameter and generic parameter?

```
public foo<T>(T abc)

public foo(object abc)
```

Actual both are kind of variable and I could convert many `Object` into anything I like to, because its the base class everything

Whatare te difeerences?

Comment: The first declaration is wrong, it must be `public T foo(T abc)`, withint a class like `class FooClass<T>`.  Also, maybe look at https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215769/how-are-generics-implemented

Comment: The explanation for that topic would either be too short and not covering all purposes of generic or simply way too long. Generic is often covered over several chapters in books.

Comment: so... whats your question? you were thinking about the differences. What about the differences? Are you asking if they essentially boil down to the same thing (tongue in cheek)

Comment: They both look similar and for me I dont know when too use the one over the other

Answer (score 2):

it's hard to tell difference without seeing your methods . If your methods are just writing the type of inputs to console, there is no difference. But if your methods are casting object and doing something there are differences.

Generics are very powerful because of constraints and they can inherit from other generics type.

So General Difference:

**Type Safety:** you can send anything, but while casting you can get error at runtime with objects. if you use constraints you will get error at compile time with generics.

**Cleaner Code:** you will always use casting with object. You don't have to do this with generics.

**Better Performance** (For Value Types): there will be no boxing and unboxing with generics. if you send value type, it will first put this memory heap (boxing) then it will get to thread stack from memory heap (unboxing) with object.

Comment: Performance is debatable. With generics, you end up with a new implementation of the genericized method, class, etc for every type you use. Without profiling, "performance" is entirely too nebulous.

Comment: Yes you are right but it is better performance with value types. Or Am I wrong ?

Comment: The question is too vague. It really depends on how often it gets called, how it is used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generics is a complex topic and I would suggest that you dive deeper if you don't understand the difference.

In short: by using object, you expose yourself to run-time exceptions when you expect object to be of type A but in fact it is of type B. Generics are there to provide type safety by removing the duty of creating many e.g. functions doing the same thing for many different types. By using generic constraints, you can create powerful and safe solutions.

Further reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

performance - when converting value type to object, boxing and unboxing are very expensive.
type safe - need to cast objects, you lose compile-time type safety.

generics solve this issues.